# Print When Expression when column shows certain data

Tags: jasper-reports

I have View called `VW_PRINT MR`, It has column called `DocStatus`, There are 3 types of Values in `DocStatus`, they are `'CO','CL','DR`.

I've tried synchronize view with Jasper Report.

How can I print `"Documents Approved"` when `DocStatus` is `CO` and `'Document has not Approved yet'` when `'DocStatus'` is `'DR'` ?

I've tried putting `$F(VW_PRINTMR_DOCSTATUS)='CO'` in Print When Expression but it won't work.

Comment: show us sample code of the `textfield`. and how u tried it

Answer (score 0):

It works! :

```
$F{VW_PRINTMR_DOCSTATUS}.replace("CO","Document is completed").replace("DR","Document has not approved").replace("CL","Document is closed").replace("AP","Document is Partially Approved").replace("IN","Document is Invalid")
```